# How to get the next status for a specific period of time?

Tags: sql

I am trying create a query that will add a column called NextStatus to the table whose value will be the Status of end date for specific period of time and a specific ID. The specified period is 18-Jan to 18-Feb. Thus, the NextStatus would be the Status on 18-Feb.

Here is sample of the data:

```
As_of_Dt  LoanID    Status
18-Jan  1410010957    C
18-Jan  1410011314    C
18-Feb  1410010957    F
18-Feb  1410011314    R
```

So there would be a new column,

```
As_of_Dt  ID        Status   NextStatus
18-Jan   10957    C           F
18-Jan   11314    C           R
18-Feb   10957    F           F
18-Feb   11314    R           R
```

As you can see the NextStatus for ID 10957 would be F and the NextStatus for ID 11314 would be R since on 18-Feb was R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(status, 1, status) over (partition by id order by as_of_dt) as nextstatus
from t;
```

This uses the three-argument form of `lead()`.  If there is not "next" row, then the third argument is the default value to return.

Comment: @QMan5 . . . I don't know if I understand what you mean.  The title is quite clear -- and the question consistent -- with wanting the *next* value.  If you want the value on a particular date, you could use a `join` or other mechanisms.

Comment: Apologies, what I mean is can I specify a specific period of time in my query while using the lead() function? The lead() seems to be what I am looking for but I also want to only look at the next status for only specified period. Does this make sense?

Comment: @QMan5 Why don't you just do `select * from (this answer) table_alias where as_of_dt='somedate'`